# SocketIO ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I am starting to use NodeJS and Socket.IO. I am trying to set up a basic example with a NodeJS http server and establish a Socket.IO connection to the server.

I am also using angular JS and basically what I want is that when a user presses a button then the connection to the server is established. However, when I try it I get this error

`GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1404288173776-3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

**Here is my code:**

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var server= http.createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello Http');
}

io.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    console.log('connected!');
});
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope){

    $scope.msg= "";

    $scope.try = function (){

        $scope.msg= "ALO"

        var socket = io('http://localhost');

        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    };

});
```

And on my test.html file:

```
<body ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    <h2>{{msg}}</h2>
    <button ng-click="try()">Try</button>

    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> -->

</body>
```

I think that the error might be something related to the path I use when including the socket.io.js I have tried also using directly localhost:8080 in the path because I read it could be a solution but that didn't work. So please, I appreciate any help given. Thanks!

Comment: I had also the same error. After this post I just cross checked the URL which I had given incorrect.Thanks.

Answer (score 66):

I faced exactly the same issue. I did not see the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in socket.io@~0.9. The error surfaced after I upgraded socket.io to 1.3.

I solved it by simply removing the URL from the client side constructor:

Change

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
```

To

```
var socket = io();
```

As the socket.io tutorial showed: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Using the implicit URL fixed it for me as well, thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. Just complementing what the example says: "Notice that I’m not specifying any URL when I call io(), since it defaults to trying to connect to the host that serves the page."

Comment: What about using different port or not hosted on local?

Answer (score 16):

If your server is listening on port 8080, you need to connect to that port.

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
```

And as you're using a relative path, the socket.io lib will be served fine.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried these two solutions before (sorry I didn't mention that) but I get a file not found error for the socket.io.js path, that's why I tried the other one. I don't know what could be the problem.

I installed socket.io using npm install socket.io and the node_modules folder containing socket io are in my users folder on windows for some reason and not in the node_modules folder that is in program files. Could that have something to do with the problem? I tried to install globally to see if it changed the location folder but it didn't :/ I don't know what else to try

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the socket.io was being installed in a funny folder and therefore it was not being recognised or loaded. I solved this by creating a package.json and declaring the dependencies there so that when I do npm install it installs the folder in the right place.

Also Ben Fortune was right and I also modified that...I hope this helps other people because I struggled A LOT to figure that out :)

Answer (score 1):

I was accessing IP of my cloud server to chat. suddenly The server was down.Then I got this polling error. Finally I figured out The problem is with that server.make sure your server is up.

I changed IP address to zero. please assume your server address

```
socket = io.connect('0.0.0.0:8110');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// SERVER running on http://localhost:9000

    const PORT = 9000;    
    const http = require('http');
    
    const httpServer = http.createServer()
    
    
    const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
        cors: {
            origin: "http://localhost:3000", // client address 
        },
    });   
    
    
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log(socket)
    })
    
    httpServer.listen(PORT);



// CLIENT


    import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
    
    const URL = "http://localhost:9000";
    const socket = io(URL, { autoConnect: false });
    socket.connect();
    console.log(socket)
    
    socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
    });
```

The socket should be listening to the app (httpServer) and app should listen  to the port. Don't mess it

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log("App listening at localhost:" + port));
```

It work for me :)

See [doc](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#integrating-socketio)