# Error 404 when trying to get socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, http-status-code-404

I am writing a node server that serves a web page using socket.io. But when I load the page, the console shows the error

> (index):6 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

which is, unsurprisingly, followed by :

> (index):51 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

when I examine the files loaded by the page in the network tab, it shows an error 404 for socket.io. But surprisingly, when I launched other programs I made that use socket.io, all worked fine. The only difference is that for this one, I use express.

Here is my code :

app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static("./app"));  

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server started in http://localhost:" + 3000);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('news', {hello :'world'});
  socket.on('my other event', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

[Some unrelated text]

<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
app.listen(3000);
```

to

```
server.listen(3000);
```

Your socket.io is attached to the http server `server`.
See line: `var io = require('socket.io')(server);`
 and Not the express server `app`.

So obviously socket.io couldn't serve anything, as the server it expected never started listening.

*TESTED! THIS ANSWER WAS SUCCESSFULLY REPLICATED IN MY LOCAL ENVIRONMENT!!*

Comment: Thanks, that was it ! For info, after I tested your solution, I got the same error that on this other thread, that I fixed using the top answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526166/socketio-err-connection-refused

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to test the fix for from the other thread before. Thanks for your help !